# How long does it take for a Tangerine no-fee money-transfer email to be delivered?

Tags: canada, money-transfer, online-banking, free, frugal

I live in Canada. I use Tangerine (formerly ING Direct). Tangerine is the "direct banking" division of Scotiabank; it has no monthly fees but also no tellers.

They let me send "Interac email money transfers", which cost $1 each. They also let me send "Tangerine email money transfers", which are free but slower.

I sent a "Tangerine email money transfer", but the recipient still hasn't received the email yet. What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I phoned Tangerine; they enlightened me.

- It generally takes **2 hours** for the email to arrive.
- Next, the recipient must open the email, click the link, and enter their bank account number. They'll generally receive the money **2-3 business days** after that.

[This forum post](https://forums.redflagdeals.com/how-long-does-take-interac-e-transfer-2086709/#p27564240) suggests that the delays are due to systemic risk management, tendering, and clearing.

Comment: ...I can't help but feel that this is a perfect way to teach people how to fall victim to scammers.

Comment: Please clarify. _What_ is a perfect way to teach people how to fall victim to scammers? Asking money-transfer recipients to click a link in an email and then enter their bank-account number?